# Powershell regex to get DC from Distinguished Name

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to get the first `DC` that appears for a given Distinguished name as below:

```
CN=blah1,CN=Computers,DC=blah2,DC=blah3
```

So in plain English I wish to "replace all strings, up to 'DC=', and return any value from `DC=` and up to the next `,`

I've tried working it out using online calculators but somehow doesn't work.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your code please.

Comment: .+?,DC=(.+?),(?:DC)

Comment: Why do you want to extract that part of the string? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: We have a few domains, and I have a further script that requires the domain names before I can run Get-ADComputer queries. I have since been able to us Split and join the last two "DC=" together. Thanks

Comment: I recommend using the **Pathname** COM object (see my answer).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`Split`](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html) is enough for this, i.e:

```
$s = "CN=blah1,CN=Computers,DC=blah2,DC=blah3"
$s.Split(",")[2].Split("=")[1]
# blah2
```

---

[Powershell Demo](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X6W4pCgzL13BVkHJ2c82KScxw1AHyHDOzy0oLQGq0nFxBosawRjGSlxQPXrBBTmZJRpKOkqa0UaxMJ4tkGcY@/8/AA)

Comment: Don't split on just the comma since a distinghuishedName **CAN** have a comma in any of the individual components of a distinguished name. In that case it is preceeded by a backslash in order to escape it.

Comment: I'm answering directly to the question and not to an hypothetical situation. To my understanding, the example string is coma-separated: `"CN=blah1,CN=Computers,DC=blah2,DC=blah3"`

Comment: Woll work only for THIS particular example, but **not** with `"CN=blah1,DC=blah2"`

Comment: Sure, but the DN the OP gave as an example **IS** just an example. We don't know the real thing and so there is no telling if any of the components uses a comma or not. As far as I'm concerned, only @Paxz does the split as it should be

Comment: @Theo Oh really, then I suggest this even simpler solution: `"CN=blah1,CN=Computers,DC=blah2,DC=blah3".substring(25, 5)`

Comment: That's fine @Theo. GL!

Comment: It does, however need to find the first instance of "DC=", as I'll be doing an Get-ADComputer from across multiple domains, and "DC="  may appear further down the line from DistinguishedName

Comment: @TOGEEK Can you please un-select my answer as the correct one? So can delete it and leave room for better answers?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

```
$str = "CN=blah1,CN=Computers,DC=blah2,DC=blah3"
$str -match '^.*?(DC=.*?),'
$Matches[1] # DC=blah2
```

It finds the first `DC=*` where `*` is whatever follows the `=` until the next comma.

Comment: Don't you think a `-split ','` would be much easier?

Comment: The question is tagged `regex` so I've provided a regex based solution @Olaf but yes, a simple `-split ','` would do the trick too... :-)

Comment: Sometimes the answer is something else ;-)  `((('CN=blah1,CN=Computers,DC=blah2,DC=blah3' -split ',')[-1]) -split '=')[1]`

Comment: @Olaf A distinghuishedName **CAN** have a comma in any of the individual components of a distinguished name. In that case it is preceeded by a backslash in order to escape it. In such a case, the split on `,` can lead to unexpected results. Uncommon I know, but..

Comment: Even the domain and the suffix (TLD) can have a comma?  ... really?  ... ok, I wasn't aware of that   ... thanks for clearing this up.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Well to show the second easy method to grep certain parts of your string. Try to use `- split`:

```
$string = "CN=blah1,CN=Computers,DC=blah2,DC=blah3"

#Seperate the string at ",DC=" and get the second part
($string -split ',DC=')[1]
```

Returns: `blah2`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best (by "best" I mean the "most robust") answer is not to do string parsing or a regex in the first place and use the [IADSPathname interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iads/nn-iads-iadspathname) to retrieve the part of the name you're interested in. This is available (albeit initially somewhat complex) in PowerShell via the **Pathname** COM object. The **Pathname** object handles all escaping of characters automatically.

Example:

```
$ADS_SETTYPE_DN = 4
$ADS_DISPLAY_VALUE_ONLY = 2

$Pathname = New-Object -ComObject Pathname

$distinguishedName = "CN=blah1,CN=Computers,DC=blah2,DC=blah3"

# Set the AD path in the object
$Pathname.GetType().InvokeMember("Set", "InvokeMethod", $null, $Pathname, @($distinguishedName,$ADS_SETTYPE_DN))

# Get the number of name elements
$numElements = $Pathname.GetType().InvokeMember("GetNumElements", "InvokeMethod", $null, $Pathname, $null)

# Retrieve the second-to-last name element (outputs "DC=blah2")
$Pathname.GetType().InvokeMember("GetElement", "InvokeMethod", $null, $Pathname, $numElements - 2)

# Set the display type to values only
$Pathname.GetType().InvokeMember("SetDisplayType", "InvokeMethod", $null, $Pathname, $ADS_DISPLAY_VALUE_ONLY)

# Retrieve the second-to-last name element (outputs "blah2")
$Pathname.GetType().InvokeMember("GetElement", "InvokeMethod", $null, $Pathname, $numElements - 2)
```

Admittedly, the **Pathname** COM object is not easy to use in PowerShell because you have to call it indirectly. This can be alleviated somewhat by using a "wrapper" function to invoke the object's methods. Example:

```
$ADS_SETTYPE_DN = 4
$ADS_DISPLAY_VALUE_ONLY = 2

$Pathname = New-Object -ComObject Pathname

function Invoke-Method {
  param(
    [__ComObject] $object,
    [String] $method,
    $parameters
  )
  $output = $object.GetType().InvokeMember($method, "InvokeMethod", $null, $object, $parameters)
  if ( $output ) { $output }
}

$distinguishedName = "CN=blah1,CN=Computers,DC=blah2,DC=blah3"

# Set the AD path in the object
Invoke-Method $Pathname "Set" @($distinguishedName,$ADS_SETTYPE_DN)

# Get the number of name elements
$numElements = Invoke-Method $Pathname "GetNumElements"

# Retrieve the second-to-last name element (outputs "DC=blah2")
Invoke-Method $Pathname "GetElement" ($numElements - 2)

# Set the display type to values only
Invoke-Method $Pathname "SetDisplayType" $ADS_DISPLAY_VALUE_ONLY

# Retrieve the second-to-last name element (outputs "blah2")
Invoke-Method $Pathname "GetElement" ($numElements - 2)
```

For a complete solution, I wrote a PowerShell module called [ADName](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PowerShell-ADName) that provides an easy-to-use interface for both the **Pathname** and the [**NameTranslate**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsnametranslate) objects.

In the ADName module, the Get-ADName cmdlet is a wrapper for the **Pathname** object, and the Convert-ADName cmdlet is a wrapper for the **NameTranslate** object. Example:

```
# Get elements of name as an array
$nameElements = Get-ADName "CN=blah1,CN=Computers,DC=blah2,DC=blah3" -Split
# Output second-to-last element (e.g., "DC=blah2")
$nameElements[-2]

# Get name elements (values only)
$nameElements = Get-ADName "CN=blah1,CN=Computers,DC=blah2,DC=blah3" -Split -ValuesOnly
# Output second-to-last element (e.g., "blah2")
$nameElements[-2]
```

I've found that the Get-ADName and Convert-ADName cmdlets are extremely useful in a variety of scenarios. One example:

```
$name = "CN=blah1,CN=Computers,DC=blah2,DC=blah3"
# Output canonical name of parent path; e.g.: "blah2.blah3/Computers"
$name | Get-ADName -Format Parent | Convert-ADName Canonical
```